# modelchoicefield django добавить пустое значение

Tags: python, django

Форма:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    uchastok = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Department.objects.filter(is_prod=True), 
                                      empty_label='все', label='Фильтровать по участку', 
                                      required=False)
    object = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Object.objects.all(), empty_label='все', 
                                    label='Фильтровать по объекту', required=False)
```

При попытке передать в качестве значения пустую строку указанная форма не проходит валидацию. Данные то я могу получить из form.data но хотелось бы чтобы форма отрабатывала без ошибок.
Форма необходима для фильтра по связанным объектам, пустая строка нужна для обработки вывода без фильтрации.